# JSONTokener crashes after .jar export from eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jar

I have a project that writes to a json file, after exporting to .jar and creating the .json externally, it will pause when clicking the button to write.

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Calendar.json");
        
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(is); //(Freezes Here)
        
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

It works perfectly when ran inside eclipse , but after export to .jar it wont get past the JSONTokener

Comment: There isn't enough context to form a useful answer. Please read [ask], then come back and edit your question.

Comment: Have you tried running the jar from a terminal to see if an error gets thrown?